# How to get formated result in mongodb aggregation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a requirement where I should generate result like below:

```
USERID |     Screen ON  time    | Screen Off time
1      | 2020-04-29 11:27:04 AM | 2020-04-29 11:33:04 AM
2      | 2020-04-29 12:27:04 AM | 2020-04-29 12:33:04 AM
3      | 2020-04-29 13:27:04 AM | 2020-04-29 13:33:04 AM
4      | 2020-04-29 13:27:04 AM | 2020-04-29 14:33:04 AM
1      | 2020-04-29 14:27:04 AM | 2020-04-29 15:33:04 AM
6      | 2020-04-29 15:27:04 AM | 2020-04-29 16:33:04 AM
2      | 2020-04-29 16:27:04 AM | 2020-04-29 17:33:04 AM
7      | 2020-04-29 17:27:04 AM | 2020-04-29 19:33:04 AM
```

The user data gets repeated as the user uses the device multiple times a day,

The schema document how the data is saved is given below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5eae9ffbc6a54e2bd0a9a3f5"),
    "user" : 1,
    "device" : 1 device,
    "type" : "sleepawake",
    "activity" : "Device Screen Off",
    "when" : ISODate("2020-05-03T07:58:36.000Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-05-03T10:42:03.083Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5eae9ffbc6a54e2bd0a9a3f6"),
    "user" : 2,
    "device" : 2 device,
    "type" : "sleepawake",
    "activity" : "Device Wakes Up",
    "when" : ISODate("2020-05-03T07:58:54.000Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-05-03T10:42:03.084Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5eae9ffbc6a54e2bd0a9a3f7"),
    "user" : 1,
    "device" : i device,
    "type" : "sleepawake",
    "activity" : "Device Screen Off",
    "when" : ISODate("2020-05-03T07:59:03.000Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-05-03T10:42:03.084Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I tried mongodb aggregation to get result as the requirement but I can't manage to get it working.

Is there any way I can generate such a result?

Expected result:

```
{
 user: 1,
 ScreenON: 2020-04-29 11:27:04 AM,
 ScreenOFF: 2020-04-29 11:42:27 AM
},
{
 user: 2,
 ScreenON: 2020-04-29 11:27:04 AM,
 ScreenOFF: 2020-04-29 11:42:27 AM
},
{
 user: 1,
 ScreenON: 2020-04-29 11:45:04 AM,
 ScreenOFF: 2020-04-29 11:52:27 AM
}
```

Comment: This data is given from the device side, the differentiation is done on the device side.

Comment: We have to do it with the activity field `"activity" : "Device Screen Off"`

Comment: @turivishal Any luck?

Comment: @turivishal updated the question, i have added the expected result

Comment: It is just an example.

Comment: The above objects are straight from mongodb collections, expect the excel sheet format and the expected result.

Comment: I am sorry i am still not getting, dates are different in your documents and expected result, it is ok someone will help you.